# how to send FormData and request body in angular httpclient

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am updating my angular application package from @angular/http to @angular/common/http.
In the process my code is breaking due to following reason

In the current version I am able to send both formdata and request body in the below way

`this.http.post(URL, formData, {'header': headerObj, 'body': bodyObj})`

but in the upgrade I am only able to send `formData` or `body` not both

`this.httpClient.post(this.hostname + apiURL, formData, options)`

I don't want to convert request body to formData object since I will be sending `null` or `undefined` to server which gets converted to string `null` which I don't want.

Is there a solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the text data as FormData, not in headers.

```
 let formData: FormData = new FormData();
 files.forEach(file => {
    formData.append(file.name, file, file.name);
 })
 formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Then you need to parse the FormData similar to how you are parsing it for the files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Angular docs for httpClient POST: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post.

You can use one of 15 overloads to POSt the data.

---

As for the form-data and the body, possible alternative is to merge them into a single object and send as *body*. Then read at the back-end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did already try that but when I convert formData to request body object the file object becomes empty if there is an attachment as part of the request